# How can I run xsp4 as a background process on linux?

Tags: mono, xsp

Is there an easy way to get xsp4 running as a background process on a linux server?

When I run xsp4 I get this:

```
xsp4
Listening on address: 0.0.0.0
Root directory: /test
Listening on port: 80 (non-secure)
Hit Return to stop the server.
```

So if I quit the terminal I am running it from it stops the server.

Do I have to write a daemon to do this?  Or is there already something in place that I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: I think I have worked it out:

    sudo xsp4 --port 80 --nonstop &

The '&' seems to get it running in the background.

Are there any problems with doing this?  Should I write a daemon to do it instead?

Comment: MonoDevelop invokes xsp with a --nonstop: https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/blob/7c51ae11c323d429c10acd22169373927217198f/main/src/addins/AspNet/Execution/AspNetExecutionHandler.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options. If your problem is terminal closing, then [screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) can be simple solution (just run screen xsp4, then Ctrl+A,D and you can close terminal). If the method you have used suits you, then use it -- however xsp will die after terminal closing. xsp should be generally used for debugging, production solutions are FastCGI or apache module, so these are daemons "by definition".

Comment: how fast will it die? how should a switch between xsp4 and FastCGI?

Comment: What do you mean by die? On its own? Due to excessive load?

Answer (score 0):

I had to use **Mono** for a demo that I had to show, and faced the same problem. My **workaround** was:

```
xsp4 --nonstop &
```

*Note*: It will show the initial information and if you hit enter, it will continue running. You can also exit the terminal if you want and it will continue as well.

Answer (score -1):

you can do  install the xsp4 in the terminal 
`sudo apt-get install mono-xsp4`
  then 
 go to your project Folder where the Asp project saved and type in the terminal
 `xsp4`